# Get devices from HealthKit

Tags: ios, swift, healthkit

[image]

Health app displays devices in Sources tab. I'd simply like to get the same information that the Health app is using to determine the type of source.

[HKSource](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksource) doesn't seem to provide that.

Is there any other way to identify which source is an iPhone or Apple Watch?

```
    let sampleType = HKObjectType.quantityType(forIdentifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier.stepCount)

    let query = HKSourceQuery(sampleType: sampleType!, samplePredicate: nil) {
        query, sources, error in


    }
    HKHealthStore().execute(query)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. I will query [HKSample](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hksample) and property [HKDevice](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkdevice) in HKSample contain information about device.

```
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    for source in sources {
        let sourceModel = SourceHealthKitModel(source: source)
        group.enter()
        let type = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForObjects(from: source)
        let query = HKSampleQuery(sampleType: type!, predicate: predicate, limit: 1, sortDescriptors: nil) { (query, results, error) in
            if let sample = results?.first {
                sourceModel.sample = sample
                self?.dataSources.append(sourceModel)
            }
            group.leave()
        }
        HKHealthStore().execute(query)
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        self?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```